# How to remove/hide the dynamic radio button by value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

How to remove/hide the radio button by value using javascript and not jquery.
I have three radio buttons which has dynamic ids and name.
I would like to know how to remove the radio button by values

I got stuck not sure how to do in javascript, on page load

```
var option_value1= ["bank", "credit", "debit"]; //show all the three buttons
var option_value2= ["bank", "credit"] //show only bank and credit radio buttons.

<form>
 <input class="form-check-input" name="sending-${provider.id}" type="radio" id="provider-send-bank transfer-${provider.id}" value="bank" checked>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="sending-${provider.id}" type="radio" id="provider-send-credit-${provider.id}" value="credit">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="sending-${provider.id}" type="radio" id="provider-send-debit-${provider.id}" value="debit">
</form>
```

```
Expect Output:
according to option_value, display radio buttons
```

Comment: `document.getElementByName("debit").outerHTML = "";`

Comment: @Kaushik “debit” is not the name. The name is `sending-${provider.id}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the `form-check-input` radio inputs and then filter each by their value. The filter will only keep elements in the array whose value is not in the `option_value` array. You can then loop over this filtered array and hide the elements.

See working example below:

```js
const option_values = [{
    id: "trans",
    options: ["bank", "credit"]
  },
  {
    id: "fund",
    options: ["bank"]
  }
];

const id = "trans";
const options = option_values.find(({id:x}) => x===id).options;

[...document.getElementsByClassName("form-check-input")].filter(({
  value
}) => !options.includes(value)).forEach(elem => elem.style.display = 'none');
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="sending-${provider.id}" type="radio" id="provider-send-bank transfer-${provider.id}" value="bank" title="bank" checked>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="sending-${provider.id}" type="radio" id="provider-send-credit-${provider.id}" value="credit" title="credit">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="sending-${provider.id}" type="radio" id="provider-send-debit-${provider.id}" value="debit" title="debit">
</form>
```

Comment: if the `option_value2 ` is array object like `const option_value2 =[{ id="trans",options: ["bank", "credit"]}, { id="fund",options: ["bank", "debit"]}]`, how to filter out options for all id

Comment: @sowmiya what does the `id` relate to in this case?

Comment: for each object `id`,  `options` should be used for radio button to display, since for each object have radiobuttons options

Comment: I have edited your answer and added my scenario, please check.

Comment: @sowmiya I've updated my answer, is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery

```
$(':radio').each(function(){
    $(this).css('display', option_value.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1 ? 'none':'');
})
```

option_value is array[string]